# Insert dot in currency amount

Tags: python, integer

**Set-up**

I have several integers that represent monetary values.

Problem is that the integers are missing a dot, i.e. `12345` should be `123.45`.

**My Code**

```
amount = str(12345)
first_amount = amount[:-2]
last_amount = amount[-2:]
order_amount = float(first_amount + '.' + last_amount)
```

this works fine, i.e. I obtain `123.45`.

I was wondering if there's a one-line solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there's a solution, dividing by `100.00`, note the `.00` part:

```
a = 12345
print(a/100.00) # prints 123.45
```